# Grails (Hibernate) does select before insert without passing id argument value

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I'm starting more serious tests of my grails web-app and it was time to move from hsqldb to postgres. Everything went more or less ok, however I'm getting an error in Bootstrap when creating test data. Hibernate tries to do a select before inserting a row into the database.
Unfortunately, when doing so it does not pass an argument to the select and I'm getting exception saying the parameter 1 value was not specified.

Here's my domain class:

```
class User {

static constraints = {
    deviceId(
            blank: false,
            unique: true,
    )
    userName(nullable: true, size: 5..15, blank: false, unique: true)
    password(nullable: true, size: 5..15, blank: false)
    email(nullable: true, email: true, blank: false, unique: true)
    blockedUsers(unique: true)
}
static mapping = {
    table "player"
    deviceId indexColumn: [name: "deviceId", unique: true]
}
static mappedBy = [inbox: 'userTo', outbox: 'userFrom']
static hasMany = [profiles: Profile, inbox: Message, outbox: Message, blockedUsers: User]

List<User> blockedUsers = new ArrayList<User>()
String deviceId
String userName
String email
String password
Boolean readyForExport = false
Boolean newUser = false
[...]
}
```

so there's nothing special about it.
Before this error I've got quite a few .save(flush:true) commands on other domains and everything is fine. It's just this one that throws the error :/

These are the lines responsible for this error.

```
User userA = new User(userName: "test", password: "dkjughey3htg", email: "integration@test.com", deviceId: 'intTestDevice')
userA.save(flush:true)
```

Any tips why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think your problem is in:

```
blockedUsers(unique:true)
```

Is there a reason why you're specifying blockedUsers as a List rather than GORM's default of Set? With Set, uniqueness of members is automatic, and then you don't have to use the unique constraint, which doesn't work as you might expect on one-to-many properties. Also, this is unrelated, but plaintext passwords are naughty.

Comment: hi Jordan. You are correct, this constraint is what's blocking execution of bootstrap however... list gives me something that set does not - correct order. In this case it is not needed, however it was done this way probably because in few other places we need the correct order and it's easier to achieve it by using list rather than other means. Yeah... plaintext passwords are naughty, buy I prefer to implement spring security as one of the last steps before public tests due to the time impact it has on grails startup ;) Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. If you want to use a list, you can do a custom constraint to test uniqueness, just not the built-in unique constraint.